# Communication Between Services Running on Different Processes in Android?

Tags: android, service, process, listener

I have created a service which runs on it own process. The service registers itself as a listener to the ClipboardManager. Everything works fine, whenever new thing copied to the clipboard, the callback method on my service is called to capture the new clip data.

My Question is, how can these two services communicate with each other although they are running on two different processes and I haven't implemented any AIDL of iBinder?!!

Thanks,,,

Answer (score 1):

Sending a Broadcast and registering a broadcast receiver in the other service may be an easy solution:

Sending broadcast:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29)

Registering a BroadcastReceiver:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

If you need to exchange and presist data using a shared ContentProvider might be a solution as well. The other service could register a ContentObserver to get notified about new / updated data.

Comment: ah haa, so.. it is all about Broadcast and broadcast receivers... there is no direct communication!!! I see... Thanks :)