# Acess variable from service which runs in separate process

Tags: android, service, process

I have created one service in my android project which runs separately in  process as i declare it in manifest like,

```
android:process=":MyService"
```

I know that once you create service in separate process;you can not access any variables from the service.But in my case i want both,

1)Run service in separate process And

2)Access variables from this service.

how can i achieve this?

Is there in trick to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there might be any direct communication. Though you can use Broadcast receivers.

[Send broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) from that service
and then [register the broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in another service

Also have a look at this answer

[Communication Between Services Running on Different Processes in Andoird?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12745068/1626878)

Comment: Thanks for your answer...i am gonna try it.But i want to use some trick or shortcut .However,I can use SharedPreferences too.

Comment: nope,SharedPreferences not working,i guess i need to use above solution

Comment: @dd619 I think broadcast receiver should have done the trick.